# Heroku: how to install an existing app from GitHub?

Tags: github, heroku

sorry for a primitive question. I am a totally new Heroku user and I want to install an app that is on GitHub. It is written on Python. I've created a pipeline on Heroku and connected my Heroku account to my GitHub account. 
Now I have absolutely no idea what to do, could you please help me?

Comment: Please add more details to your question, it makes it a lot easier to make suggestions. For example, where are you stuck, what errors are you seeing, what have you tried, etc...

Comment: Sorry, but that's all the information that I have. No more details. Sorry for that. I am stuck right after I have created my Heroku account, because I had no time yet to read their documentation. As I mentioned I've created a pipeline and connected both accounts. I am not sure how to get started to install the app there. Is there any general information on how to install an existing Python-based app on Heroku? If my explanations are not detailed enough, could you please at least give me the links to an appropriate manual or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to push your code from your local machine to Heroku the Heroku CLI. You can install it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

1. Create an app. Run `heroku create`. This will make an app on your account and add a Git remote called `heroku.
2. Push your code with `git push heroku master`

This "getting started" doc may help as well: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Comment: No, the project code is currently on GitHub, should I download it first?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest. There are also ways to push from Github directly to Heroku. You can read more about that here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration